# Forest: Search for a node matching criterion

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I am using forest to draw data structures (in particular AVL- / (a,b)-trees).
I want to draw connecting lines between all leaves automatically (so far I have manually named them and drawn lines using foreach statements, which is a bit annoying).

The following somewhat works:

```latex
for tree={edge={->},if n children=0{}{treenode}},
for leaves={leafnode,tier=list,if={id()!=id("!rL")}{tikz={\draw[<->,thick,gray] () -- (!>);}}{}},
for root={rootnode}
[5 & 19,align=cc
  [5] [19] [$\infty$]
]
```

(the `id()!=id("!rL")` is the only way I could come up with to detect whether the current leaf is not the last one, as there `!>` is not defined)

However, I also want to animate insertion/deletion of nodes without changing the layout, i.e. add phantom nodes

```latex
for tree={edge={->},if n children=0{}{treenode}},
for leaves={leafnode,tier=list,if={id()!=id("!rL")}{tikz={\draw[<->,thick,gray] () -- (!>);}}{}},
for root={rootnode}
[5,align=c
  [5] [,phantom] [$\infty$]
]
```

Now, the phantom node is still treated as the next (later non-existent) sibling, but I would want to draw a line from the node 5 to the $\infty$ node directly.

Can I somehow search for the next non-phantom (or non-empty-content) sibling?
I couldn't wrap my head around the `while` / `until` constructs of forest and examples seem to be sparse.

EDIT: Abstractly, I think the question reduces to "how can I get a handle on the first node satisfying a criterion in a nodewalk"

EDIT2: MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,forest}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{box/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum height=0.7cm,minimum width=1cm}}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={edge={->},anchor=north,box},
        for leaves={tier=list,if={id()!=id("!rL")}{tikz={\draw[<->] () -- (!>);}}{}},
        [x
            [a]
            [b]
            [c]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you extend your code fragments into a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can copy/paste/trial solutions please?

Comment: oops, yes, sorry! Added. I pruned it down to the bare minimum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's two ways to do this. Both deploy the same basic idea: we visit the non-phantom leaves, use `alias'=last` to remember the previously visited node and get the `id` of the previous node into the `tikz` code using `.process` handler. (We only draw when `last` points to a valid node, this is checked by `if nodewalk valid`, and we initialize `last` to an invalid node at the start.)

The first way uses `where` to visit the non-phantom leaves. The first argument is a `pgfmath` expression. A combination of `where n children` and `if phantom` would work as well. (Note that `where` is technically speaking not a nodewalk.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum height=0.7cm,minimum width=1cm}}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={edge={->},anchor=north,box},
  % We delay to process the "phantom"s in the tree first:
  delay={
    % Set name "last" to an invalid node. Argh, cumbersome:
    for nodewalk={on invalid={fake}{id=0,alias'=last}}{},
    % Visit the non-phantom leaves:
    where={n_children==0 && !phantom}{
      if nodewalk valid={name=last}{% Do we have the "last" node?
        % Yes. Identifying the current node inside \draw is not a problem:
        % "()".  Possibly the best way to refer to the last node inside TikZ
        % code (which is executed much much later) is to paste its "id" there.
        % In ".process", "O" gets the option (name.option), and "w" injects
        % that into the code as "#1".
        tikz+/.process=Ow {last.id}{
          \draw[red, thick]()--(!id=#1);
        },
      }{% The "false" branch of "if nodewalk valid".
      },
      % Name the current node as last.
      alias'=last,
    }{% The "false" branch of "where".
    },
  },
  [x
    [a]
    [b]
    [,phantom]
    [c]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The second way uses a real nodealk.  We `filter` nodewalk `leaves` using `pgfmath` expression `!phantom`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum height=0.7cm,minimum width=1cm}}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={edge={->},anchor=north,box},
  delay={
    for nodewalk={on invalid={fake}{id=0,alias'=last}}{},
    % Filtering: walk the leaves of the tree, and step on those that are not phantom.
    for filter={leaves}{!phantom}{
      if nodewalk valid={name=last}{
        tikz+/.process=Ow {last.id}{
          \draw[red, thick]()--(!id=#1);
        },
      }{},
      alias'=last,
    },
  },
  [x
    [a]
    [b]
    [,phantom]
    [c]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: The result of both variants]

Comment: Nice! Its crazy how powerful pgf and forest are. This definitely helps to understand how nodewalks works :)

Comment: Is there a good source for learning this witchcraft? :-)

Comment: Yeah: sleep with the Forest reference under your pillow. :D

Comment: Surely writing it first must have helped?

Answer (score 2):

After posting I stumbled upon the `define long step` example in the forest doc.
This does seem to work:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,forest}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{box/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum height=0.7cm,minimum width=1cm}}
    \forestset{
        define long step={nextleaf}{n args=0}{do while={>{O}{phantom}}{next on tier}},
        connect leaves/.style={delay={if={>{O!P&}{phantom}{id()!=id("!rL")}}{tikz={\draw[-] () -- (!nextleaf);}}{}}}
    }
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={anchor=north,box},
        for leaves={tier=list,connect leaves}
        [x
            [a]
            [b]
            [c]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

But I still can't figure out a nicer way check if the current node is on the end of the tree.